# How to stop IIS asking authentication for default website on localhost

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, authentication

I have IIS 5.1 installed on Windows XP Pro SP2. Besides I have installed VS 2008 Express with .NET 3.5. So obviously IIS is configured for ASP.NET automatically for .NET 3.5

The problem is whenever I access http://localhost IE & Firefox both presents authentication box. Even if I enter Administrator user and its password, the authentication fails. I have already checked the anonymous user access (with IUSR_ user and password is controlled by IIS) in Directory Security options of default website.

However other deployed web apps work fine (does not ask for any authentication).

In IE this authentication process stops if I add http://localhost in Intranet sites option.

Please note that the file system is FAT32 when IIS is installed.

Regards,
Jatan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is most likely a NT file permissions problem. IUSR_ needs to have file system permissions to read whatever file you're requesting (like /inetpub/wwwroot/index.htm).

If you still have trouble, check the IIS logs, typically at \windows\system32\logfiles\W3SVC*.

Comment: To add a solution to this great suggestion, normally most servers have a directory where all of their websites are contained. E.g. C:\ClientSiteData or such. Your Website home directory will normally be in its own folder such as "my site" and it's normally the child elements inside that folder that do not have the needed permissions. If you right click on your site's root folder and then go to "Security" and then "advanced" at the bottom and then in the next dialogue tick "replace permissions entries on all child objects..." this will force your website files to inherit and be accessible.

Answer (score 14):

IIS uses Integrated Authentication and by default IE has the ability to use your windows user account...but don't worry, so does Firefox but you'll have to make a quick configuration change.

1) Open up Firefox and type in about:config as the url

2) In the Filter Type in ntlm

3) Double click "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" and type in localhost and hit enter

4) Write Thank You To Blogger

As Always, Hope this helped you out.

This was copied from [link text](http://forums.codecharge.com/posts.php?post_id=81959)

Answer (score 6):

It could be because of couple of Browser settings. Try with these options checked..

Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Enable Integrated Windows Authentication (works with Integrated Windows Authentication set on IIS)

Tools > Internet Options> Security > Local Intranet > Custom Level > Automatic Logon

Worst case, try adding localhost to the Trusted sites.

If you are in a network, you can also try debugging by getting a network trace. Could be because of some proxy trying to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to remove the "Default Web Site" and create a new one if you do not have any limitations.

I did it and my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want authentication try domainname\administrator as the username.

If you don't want authentication then remove all the tickboxes in the authenticated access section of the direcory security > edit window.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Admin user with password
2. Go to wwwroot props
3. Give this user a full access to this folder and its children
4. Change the user of the AppPool to the added user using this article
   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx
5. Change the User of the website using this article
   http://techblog.sunsetsurf.co.uk/2010/07/changing-the-user-iis-runs-as-windows-2008-iis-7-5/
   Put the same username and password you have created at step (1).

It is working now  congrats

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me is ,,,

Click Start>control panel>Administrative Tools>Internet Information Services

Expand the left tree, right-click your WebSite>Properties

Click on Directory Security, then in "Anonymous access and authentication control" click on Edit

Enable Anonymous access>browse> enter the credentials of the admin (like Administrator) (check names),> Click OK

Apply the settings and it should work fine.

Comment: I don't think that allowing a web user to run your web app as admin is a good idea. That sounds to me like you'll be providing a higher permission level than should normally be allowed.