# Keeps being prompted for credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication

What I did so far:

1. Created the website with this web.config (this is just the settings part, not the entire file :) )

   ```
   <appSettings>
   <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
   <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
   <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
   <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
   </appSettings>
   <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
   <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
   </system.web>
   ```
2. Created a controller:

   ```
   [Authorize(Users = @"myPcName\myUserName,skynet\Simple")]
   public class AuthenController : Controller
   {
       [Authorize(Users = @"myPcName\myUserName")]
       public ActionResult ForAdministrator()
       {
           return View();
       }
       [Authorize(Users = @"myPcName\Simple")]
       public ActionResult ForUser()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```

I got my credentials by : cmd -> whoami

3. I published my mvc site in release mode to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\backoffice
4. in IIS: 
   [image]
5. I even added my site to Local intranet in intranet options, and also:
   [image]

it just keeps prompting me again and again for credentials:

[image]

Comment: Because you specified the user authentication to **prompt for username and password** in the security settings!

Comment: Does it work if you just use `[Authorize]`? It could be that you don't need to specify the PC name and it doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the username

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop IIS asking authentication for default website on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53464/how-to-stop-iis-asking-authentication-for-default-website-on-localhost)

Comment: Hi @Kaj, it still doesn't work even if I set in internet options to "anonymous logon"

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI, it's not. I tried the suggestions there, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to try to help anyone who bumps into this question:
what I did that solved the problem was:
click the project in VS.
press F4 to go to properties
Set "Anonymus Authentication" as Disabled

in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

and in your controller:

```
    [Authorize(Users = @"pcName\user")]
    public ActionResult ForAdministrator()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Authorization with windows authentication (user)
    [Authorize(Users = @"pcName\user")]
    public ActionResult ForUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

where pcName is the name of your pc (not the WORKGROUP!)

In that way you can control who is allowed (since Anonymus Authentication is disabled).

Hope it helps someone.
Rotem